# How to stop left to right moving image for sometime and start over again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stop for sometime the left to right moving image at the end(right) and start over again the loop.I tired with the help of this website link,

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_animation-delay

but i am unable to stop for sometime and start over again.Someone can help me with this please?

Thanks for your valuable time

Comment: It would be nice if you could show us what you tried so far.

Comment: I have tried with CSS animation-properties like animation-delay,animation-duration,animation-fill-mode: forwards and backwards etc..since few hours  in the mentioned website editor only.I didn't get the desire result with none of them.And, unfortunately  when i refreshed the editor  to try something it got back to default code.

Comment: And i have tried with animation mymove: 5s steps(3) forwards; it just stopped at  the right end after 3 frames moved.but not starting the loop again.and am unable to do that.Please help on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a 5 second animation with a 10 second delay, you'd use 33%, based on the formula:  `100/(maxTime)*animationTime`

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    animation: mymove 15s infinite;
}


@-webkit-keyframes mymove {
    0% {left: 0px;}
    33% {left: 200px;}
    100% {left: 200px;}
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Neil,Thanks for your time. Yes,but it has to stop at the right end for at least 10s and don't need to move back(right-left) instead just need to move left to right again.Any help on it please.

Comment: @krish Updated it.  Please do remember to mark as solution, it helps a lot.